# List comprehension and % function

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

When I am using the following code

```
[i for i in range(-9, 10, 2) if not i%3)]
```

it gives

```
> (-9, -3, 3, 9)
```

Why does it give that answer? What does the `'i%3'` mean?

Thank you.

Comment: `mylist = []` is redundant. I'm removing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, `%` is the [modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations). `a % b` returns the remainder of `a / b`.

So in your example, the loop goes through:

```
[-9, -7, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

`-9 % 3` is equal to 0, because -9 is divisible by 3, and thus there is no remainder. However, `5 % 3` returns 2, because 3 goes into 5 one time, and `5 - 3 == 2`.

`not i % 3` is a bit tricky. First, `i % 3` is evaluated. If the result is greater than 0, then it is considered `True`. `not` is a boolean operator which gets the negative of a boolean. So `not True` is `False` (and `not False is True`).

`0` is considered `False`, so if `i % 3 == 0`, then `i` will be included in the new list.

---

Now, the reason why `print("%s %s", ("hello", "world"))` prints "hello world" is because that isn't the modulo operator. That's [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). The docs will explain it better than me :p. It just happens that `%` is also used.

Answer (score 2):

`i%3` is the remainder when dividing `i` by 3. However, it's then converted to a boolean (true/false) value by the `not` operator; python does this by making 0 `false` and any other number `true`. So `not i%3` is true whenever `i%3` is 0; in other words, when `i` is divisible by 3.

`range(-9,10,2)` produces integers starting at -9, incrementing by 2, as long as they are less than 10. In other words, odd integers between -9 and +9. So the combination is to select odd integers divisible by 3 between -9 and +9, which are precisely the integers you show `(-9, -3, 3, 9)`

Comment: so the definition of the '%' is that it is a divider?

Comment: @Emma It's actually called the modulo operator. There's a section [here in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

Comment: @Haidro or rici 

Can either of you explain why this:

print("%s %s", ("hello", "world"))

gives hello world

Comment: @Emma Ah, may I post an answer on that?

Comment: yes do whatever you like! thanks for the help, hope these questions aren't too silly

Comment: @Emma No actually, this is a great question. I'm upvoting it

Comment: @Emma The behaviour of `%`  can be customized for each object. On numbers it acts as a modulus, on strings it performs old string formatting. I recommend new string formatting `'{0}'.format(1)` as opposed to `'%d' % 1`